# Click on a dropdown element menu with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an administration task, so far I have made selenium to click on an element to show a dropdown menu.

[image]

When it comes the time to click on one of those menu elements I've got an error saying that the element must be displayed.

Code:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 driver.get(url)
 doc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.ms-vb-title > table')
 try:
    doc.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//menu/span[5]')
    time.sleep(4)
    print dir(menu)
    menu.click()
 except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aprobar_docs.py", line 22, in main
    menu.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 52, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 205, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 156, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 147, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element must be displayed to click'
```

As you can see the code waits a lot to get the element loaded. I've also tried to set the element's `is_displayed` property to `True` but didn't work neither.

Note: the element that's not displayed is the one on the xpath search, it is present because I've logged it with dir(menu)

**Edit:**

The `menu` variable is not the menu itself it's one of the spans that are elements of the menu, `doc` is the `Perfil` html element getting clicked to show the dropdown.

**Edit 2:**

Inspecting the DOM on chrome tools, when you click a `doc` a new menu gets created on the tree, I don't know if it's because of an ajax call or vanilla js, I don't think it's really that important how it's created. I can't retrieve it from the page and make a python object from it, it's just not being displayed at least on code.

**Final Edit:**

I ended up executing some JavaScript to make it work. Apparently when Selenium finds the menu item the first element that triggers the menu drop down loses the focus and it makes the menu invisible again, if you don't select a menu item and wait for some time the menu dropdown still is shown, if you try to select one element from the menu the menu disappears.

Comment: Why are you sleeping on both sides of the `menu` element lookup?  If the element isn't visible when you retrieve the page element, webdriver won't be able to click it, no matter how long you wait.

Comment: @sr2222 The page is retrieved when you call driver.get(), the dropdown is displayed on the screen and present on the dom tree when you do doc.click(), i just eliminated the possibility of the dropdown menu not being loaded as fast as code is executed. The menu element is present and visible, at least to humans, i can guarantee that.

Comment: Try extracting `doc` again after clicking and waiting for the menu to display, and compare the `id` attribute of the objects from before and after.  I have a sneaking suspicion that the selenium server is actually referencing a cached webelement object on your second element extraction (since your click action doesn't trigger a page load event, the page object doesn't go stale).

Comment: Are you sure the span is what is clickable in this case?  In order to be clickable, an element must have dimensions and be visible.  You might have to click some element in the span rather than the span itself.

Comment: @sr2222 `<span type="option" text="Eliminar" ...></span>`, it has nothing inside of it.

Comment: Do you have selenium IDE?  Might be instructive to see what that identifies the clicked element as.

Comment: The page requires a password (which i don't have access to) and it is saved on chrome and ie but not on firefox. As far as i know the ide is only available to firefox, now i wonder if i there's more information on the ide than on the chrome dev tools.

Comment: The IDE is just a last ditch cheat to try to see what Selenium wants you to do.  It doesn't always work.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you select an option like this

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_select')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'The Options I Am Looking For':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
```

If your click is not firing an ajax call to populate your list, you don't actually need to execute the click.

Comment: @Nllesh Sharma I used this approach but I am getting an error that web element object is not iterable. How you are iterating over it in the for loop if it is not iterable

Comment: @abhi are you sure using find_elementSSSSS_by_tag_name()? (just to have sure you saw that S hehe)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the link of the target. You don't *really* click elements, you click links...  (or rather, you click elements with links inside them).  That being said, the most sure fire way to click a link is to isolate the link element.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('this_is_your_frame_name') 
links = frame.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
links[1].click()
```

or alternatively,

```
for link in links:
    if link.text() == "Administratar Permisos":
        link.click()
```